# Does "Avoid dependency injection frameworks" in the Android Memory Guide apply to Dagger as well?

Tags: android, performance, dependency-injection, dagger

So I have come across this best practices on Android articles on memory performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

They said

> Avoid dependency injection frameworks
>
> Using a dependency injection framework such as Guice or RoboGuice may
>   be attractive because they can simplify the code you write and provide
>   an adaptive environment that's useful for testing and other
>   configuration changes. However, these frameworks tend to perform a lot
>   of process initialization by scanning your code for annotations, which
>   can require significant amounts of your code to be mapped into RAM
>   even though you don't need it. These mapped pages are allocated into
>   clean memory so Android can drop them, but that won't happen until the
>   pages have been left in memory for a long period of time.

But what about [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger) which they claim to be fast. Not sure which one should I go for?

Comment: Why this question have -6 votes and is marked as primarily opinion-based??

The author is simple asking if the Dagger framework fits in the context describe in the text provide by the android developer guide, which is a legible question (not opinion-based)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This recommendation does *not* apply equally to all dependency injection frameworks.

> ..frameworks [that work like Guice] tend to perform a lot of process initialization by *scanning your code for annotations*, which can *require significant amounts of your code to be mapped into RAM* even though you don't need it..

Thus, if using a DI/IoC framework that *doesn't* scan for said [run-time] annotations, implying the [excessive] use of reflection, then this reason doesn't apply. While [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) does use annotations these are [used *differently*](http://dig.floatingsun.net/dagger-vs-guice/) than by Guice<sup>1</sup> and avoid the problem stated.

Since Dagger was written as "A *fast* dependency injector *for Android* and Java", the authors have designed it for this purpose and believe that it is suitable for such a target - go ahead, give it a try.

---

<sup>1</sup> Dagger uses compile-time annotations (well, [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695062/is-there-documentation-on-when-dagger-falls-back-to-reflection-when-injecting-de?rq=1)) instead of relying on run-time annotations and reflection; it is the run-time annotation scanning and reflection that causes the issue the memory guide was warning about.

Comment: I've created an [issue for the android docs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213009&thanks=213009&ts=1465906273). please vote for this issue.

Comment: Toothpick is also a good alternative to Dagger, with the same performances and memory foot print: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick

Answer (score 15):

The Android team has recently updated their recommendation to [suggest developers use Dagger 2](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#DependencyInjection).

The previous recommendation was based on the high cost of reflection.  Since Dagger 2 no longer uses reflection - Dagger 1 did - they believe it ***"can be used in Android apps without needless runtime cost or memory usage"***.

(Disclaimer: I'm the Dagger 2 team manager.)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of Dagger, @JakeWharton, also wrote a simpler view "injection" framework called [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

> [because all the RoboGuice converts were complaining about lack of
>   "view injection" with Dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821148/difference-between-dagger-and-butterknife-android/30937014#30937014).

You use it like this:

> ```
> class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
>   @InjectView(R.id.title) TextView title;
>   @InjectView(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
>   @InjectView(R.id.footer) TextView footer;
>
>   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
>     ButterKnife.inject(this);
>     // TODO Use "injected" views...
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency injection](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection) best practices articles were recently added to Android developer official website. In these articles developers are encouraged to use Dagger 2 as a primary DI library for project medium (4-7 screens) and large (8+ screens) apps.

> Dagger facilitates using DI in your app by creating and managing the graph of dependencies for you. It provides fully static and compile-time dependencies addressing many of the development and performance issues of reflection-based solutions such as Guice.